# Code First Entity Framework Virtual and Foreign Key Confusions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have some POCO classes:

```
public class Device : DbEntity
{
  public string DeviceName {get;set;}
}
public class AUT : DbEntity
{
  public string ApplicationName {get;set;}
}
public class Setup : DeviceAppDbEntity
{
  public bool Worked {get;set;}
}

public class DbEntity
{
  public Guid ID {get;set;}
}
public class DeviceAppDbEntity : DbEntity
{
  public virtual AUT ApplicationUnderTesting {get;set;}
  public virtual Device DeviceUnderTesting {get;set;}
}
```

So if I want to delete an AUT (Application) then I will almost certainly get an error because Setup has a foreign key to App. I've been told that if you add

```
public class DeviceAppDbEntity : DbEntity
{
  public virtual AUT ApplicationUnderTesting {get;set;}
  public Guid ApplicationUnderTestingId {get;set;} // THIS LINE ADDED

  public virtual Device DeviceUnderTesting {get;set;}
}
```

Then cascade delete will be enabled. Is this correct?

When I now access the Setups

```
_repository.Setups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(setupID));
```

The navigation property `virtual AUT` & `virtual Device` should be automatically filled out?? Will the `Guid ApplicationUnderTestingId` be automatically filled out?

When I want to save my `Setup` entity, then can I just fill out the nav property? or do I have to fill out the `Guid ApplicationUnderTestingId` field as well, or do I do the reverse and only fill out the `Guid ApplicationUnderTestingId`?

```
entityToSave.AUT = _repository.AUTs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(vm.AppID));
```

or

```
entityToSave.ApplicationUnderTestingId= vm.AppID;
entityToSave.AUT = _repository.AUTs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(vm.AppID));
```

or

```
entityToSave.ApplicationUnderTestingId= vm.AppID;
```

This is kinda confusing.. It gets worse when you define a `List<entities>`, because when you delete the entity which contains the list. It complains about the entities within the list having relationships, how do you enable cascade delete on these?

```
public class Blog: DbEntity
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual Member {get;set;}

  public List<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}
```

I know it seems like a lot of questions, but it revolves around one topic in entity framework.Thank you for anytime spent answering my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this.

`Cascade On Delete` is enable when you do navigation properties such as

```
public virtual SomeClass {get;set;}
public Guid SomeClassId {get;set;}
```

You can fill out either of them and it will save to the database.

`No Cascade On Delete`

```
public virtual SomeClass SomeClass {get;set;}
```

When you read from the database I do mine like below:

```
var item = _repository.SomeClasses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
```

The navigation properties will only be filled out when you want to access them, lazy loading, because I used the keyword `virtual`

As far as the `List<Post>` goes, if you do:

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual Blog Blog {get;set;}
    public Guid BlogId {get;set;}
}
```

Then when a blog is deleted, all the posts associated with it will be deleted. I haven't tried to see what happens if you remove `BlogId`, but I'm guessing, when you delete a blog then none of the posts will be deleted. The `Blog => Post` model isn't the model to demonstrate why you would want to do this though.

I think I have answered all my questions. To sum up though, it all depends on `public Guid SomeClassId {get;set;}` as to whether `Cascade On Delete` is set or not.